# Homology of complements and homotopy equivalence

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, duality

Albrecht Dold gave a short proof of the Jordan-Alexander complement theorem in the following form.

Given two closed sets $A$, $B \subset {\bf R}^n$ that are homeomorphic, the singular homology groups $H({\bf R}^n \setminus  A)$ and $H({\bf R}^n \setminus B)$ are isomorphic.

*Does this result hold when $A$ and $B$ are just homotopy equivalent closed sets?*

In principle, this should follow from Alexander duality,
$$
H^\#_{n-q-1}({\bf R}^n \setminus  A) \simeq H^q(A)
$$
but this does not hold for all closed sets $A$, additional conditions are needed. Alexander duality holds in full for Alexander-Spanier homology, but this does not always coincide with singular homology.

**EDIT** : as pointed out by Dave Benson, the homotopy invariance should be understood with respect to proper homotopy maps. In his book on algebraic topology, Dold shows that there is an isomorphism
$$
H^\#_{n-q-1}({\bf R}^n \setminus  A) \simeq \check{H}_c^q(A)
$$
where the last cohomology module refers to Cech cohomology with compact support. So I guess this all boils down to invariance of these cohomology modules with respect to proper homotopy maps but I am unable to locate this result in the literature at the moment.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870942/homotopy-invariance-for-compactly-supported-cohomology

Comment: I finally found the proper homotopy invariance of Cech cohomology with compact support stated in Dold, VIII, 6.26, lectures on algebraic topology, so that solves the question.

Comment: Some relevant statements are recorded in Massey's paper [A Generalization of the Alexander Duality Theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24893112). The paper has a sequel in which the stable homotopy type of the complements are compared.

Answer (score 5):

What about $A$ is a point and $B$ is a hyperplane?

Comment: Indeed this seems to give a counterexample. I am confused. Alexander duality certainly holds for a point and an hyperplane. Ah, I see that Alexander duality holds for compactly supported homology groups. But Dold does not use homology with compact support.

Comment: Yes, compactness seems to be the key. I wonder about homotopy equivalent compact sets, for example.

Comment: It seems that shape theory is relevant to the answer, see the papers of RB Sher for example.